# How do code themes in codename one?

Tags: java, codenameone

I am a true beginner, but I want to create the look of my mobile app using code. I create a background using a photoshopped image, but I want to code the buttons and everything else in. Here is what I have (the buttons I added are not showing up):

```
public void start() {
        if(current != null){
            current.show();
            return;
        }
        new StateMachine("/theme");        
    }
    Button customer = new Button("Customer");
    Button gpsAntenna = new Button("Find An Antenna Near You");
    Button learnMore = new Button("Learn More About NEN Now");
    Button nenNow = new Button("NEN Now Webpage");
    public void stop() {
        current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
        if(current instanceof Dialog) {
            ((Dialog)current).dispose();
            current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add them to the form or a container. Look at the Form class and the Container class, I think they both have an addComponent() method. Then you may need to revalidate the form to get them to show up.

If you add them to a container, it would need to be added to the form.

Comment: Also check out this video from Steve where he goes over it step by step: http://www.codenameone.com/blog/psd-to-app-converting-a-beautiful-design-into-a-native-mobile-app.html you can also see a more textual step by step writeup of the same process (slightly simplified) in the developer guide: https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-theming.html#_converting_a_psd_to_a_theme

Comment: Ok, great! I think the preexisting code that came with the "getstarted app" theme was confusing me. I deleted all of the preexisting code and I now have the most basic features at least showing up. Thanks.